# EF Core in Modular System

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm start developing modular system with asp.net core.
the system has module loader, module installer and so on.
each module has it's own database model that dynamically add to `Context`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      var typeToRegisters = new List<Type>();
      foreach (var module in GlobalConfiguration.Modules)
      {
          typeToRegisters.AddRange(module.Assembly.DefinedTypes.Select(t => t.AsType()));
      }

      RegisterEntities(modelBuilder, typeToRegisters);
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

private static void RegisterEntities(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, IEnumerable<Type> typeToRegisters)
{
      var entityTypes = typeToRegisters.Where(x => x.GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(typeof(IEntity<>)) && !x.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract);
      foreach (var type in entityTypes)
      {
          modelBuilder.Entity(type);
      }
}
```

But EF Core doesn't work without migration.
i can create all the migrations file for all modules and run it in start, but it's wrong. maybe a module doesn't need to be install at all.

is there any way that each module bring it's own migration?
or any way to solve this?

Sorry for my bad English

Thanks

Comment: I fear not, migrations must be created before deployment and per concrete context. You could use `context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync` / `context.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync` (it doesn't require migrations to exist at deployment time), but that will create/drop the database as a whole, including loss of previous data. Probably not what you want ;)

Comment: It sounds like you are building an inner platform.

Comment: @Tseng yeah, that's what i want but thanks for your comment

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes, there's a platform that manage module loading. it's bootstraper

Comment: You will have to create migrations for all db contexts and then once you want to use one of the contexts call `context.Database.Migrate()`

Comment: @Mats391 i just have one `context`. each module's model and mapping configuration dynamically load to this `context`

Comment: The reason I commented regarding an "inner platform" was specifically because you mentioned a custom module loader. Module loading, especially in the inevitable context of multi-versioning, is a complex problem but is something that .NET has historically done far better than any other ecosystem. I do not have much experience with .NET Core, but on the CLR, module-loading (with full side-by-side multi-versioning) is a beautiful thing I would be loathe to reinvent as it is one of the few implementations that works. Most systems don't even try. (not trying to derail discussion)

Comment: @Aluan You talk about that .NET Core have its own modular system? Is there any links? I am trying to do modular system for my site as this question.

Comment: @DmitrijPolyanin no it doesn't. You misunderstood my remark. I just meant that .NET has a great module system and it would be silly to create your own on top of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But EF Core doesn't work without migration.

It works! EF Core isn't like EF 6.x and it doesn’t have automatic migrations concept. So unless you ask for applying pending migrations using `context.Database.Migrate()` method, it won't check the migrations history table at all. So EF Core doesn't need an explicit migration. To test it, just run your application and then you will see it will complain about missing tables and fields, related to your actual executed queries. It doesn't complain about missing migrations history at all. In this case you can create your database tables separately, without using the migrations and it will work just fine.
So to work independently form the migrations (this is your question), create an interface like

```
public interface  IModuleDatabaseScript
{
   string CreateSqlSchema { get;}
}
```

And then your modules should implement this interface and provide the create database/create table/alter table/drop table, etc.
Then your context should read these scripts and then run them using  `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` method. You should do this when a module is being loaded to memory once. In this case each module can have or not (just return empty CreateSqlSchema string) database creation strategy, without using the EF Core's migration mechanism.

Comment: it's sounds good, really good, thanks. just one question, how about using `MigrationBuilder` in `IModuleDatabaseScript` interface?

Comment: @Masoud use `var sql = dbContext.GetService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator>().Generate(migratonBuilder.Operations, model: null);`

Comment: @bricelam but how to get IMigrationsSqlGenerator? How it appears in DI?